# Set up 4 ip addresses with Subnet mask 255.255.255.252 (30)

Tags: networking, ip, centos6, subnet, ovh

i bought 4 ip addresses on OVH.
Then they gave me this details:

```
84.84.184.176/30
Network IP: 84.84.184.176
Broadcast IP: 84.84.184.179
Gateway IP: 84.84.184.178
Netmask: 255.255.255.252
```

And they assigned me mac addresses.

```
IP and Mask Details: 
IP 1: 84.84.184.176
MAC: 00:50:56:56:56:aa

IP 2: 84.84.184.177
MAC: 00:50:56:56:56:bb

IP 3: 84.84.184.178
MAC: 00:50:56:56:56:cc

IP 4: 84.84.184.179
Mac: 00:50:56:56:56:dd
```

But the problem is if i add the gateway on each ip address then nothing works anymore if i assigned the gateway ip `84.84.184.178`.

I'm using CentOS.

Thanks for each idea in Advance :)

Comment: The way I read that, you only have one usable IP address, 84.84.184.177. the network address isn't usable because it defines the subnet, the broadcast address isn't usable because it's the broadcast address, and the gateway address you've been given is presumably the IP address of the provider's router for you to get to the internet.  Can you qualify "nothing works"?

Comment: You didn't buy 4 IP addresses.  You bought 2 IP Address.  You cannot use the Broadcast IP for anything, and you cannot use the Gateway IP for anything other than a Gateway point.  You can only use `.176` and `.177`.  Please elaborate on the issues you're having.  Are you using the Subnet mask `255.255.255.252` with your IPs?

Comment: Are you trying to set up more than one machine? Or are you trying to give a single machine more than one address?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

/30 network gives you only two useable IP addresses (other two are network and broadcast) and one of them is the gateway, so essentially they gave you one static IP address which is 84.84.185.177. Assign this address to your interface, set network mask to 255.255.255.252, set your default gateway to 84.84.185.178 and it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set them up this way unless you have routed the block of IP addresses to a vRack. And, with such a small block, you should not attempt to route it to a vRack or you'll only have one usable IP address.

If you route the block directly to your dedicated server, you may use each address individually with a /32 prefix and your existing default gateway.

For instance:

```
IPADDR=198.51.100.107
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=198.51.100.254
```

is your server's main IP address, while

```
IPADDR2=203.0.113.176
PREFIX2=32
IPADDR3=203.0.113.177
PREFIX3=32
IPADDR4=203.0.113.178
PREFIX4=32
IPADDR5=203.0.113.179
PREFIX5=32
```

are the secondaries.

If you want to assign them to bridged virtual machines, then you don't set up the secondary IP addresses in the host. You'll need to set virtual MAC addresses in the OVH control panel, then create VMs with those MAC addresses and the host's gateway, like:

```
IPADDR=203.0.113.176
PREFIX=32
GATEWAY=198.51.100.254
```

Answer (score 0):

The information that OVH has given you is inconsistent and/or incomplete. You will have to get them to do a better job.
I suspect that the information about network / broadcast / gateway does not apply and can be simply disregarded. OVH will probably supply you with an IP address outside the /30 that you will need to use as a default gateway.